# Given that $\csc A=-\frac{5}{2}$ and $\sin A< 0$, find $\cot A$

Tags: trigonometry

Trig question, **Given that $\csc A=-\frac{5}{2}$ and $\sin A< 0$, find $\cot A$**

Ive done this so far, although my answer is abit off, where the correct answer is $-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sqrt{21}$ while my answer is missing the negative. Can you please spot the mistake?[image]

Comment: Why did you assume that $\cos\alpha$ was positive? That doesn't match your title at all.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: The title says that $\csc$ is negative **and** $\sin$ is negative. Seems kind of strange, since if $\csc$ is negative, then $\sin$ automatically is. And then we don't know the sign of $\cos$, so can't find the sign of $\cot$.

Comment: My guess is that $\cos\alpha>0$ is supposed to be the extra condition, and the wrong problem was written above the photo.  Please clarify, Red Queen10101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

If $\csc A=-\frac52<0, -\sin A=\frac1{\csc A}=-\frac25$

So, $\sin A<0$ is redundant information

We can not determine the sign of $\cot A$ from here

We can just use $$\cot A=\pm\sqrt{\csc^2A-1}$$

As Jonas Meyer has pointed out $\cos A>0$

So, $\tan A=\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}<0$ as  $\sin A<0$

$\implies \cot A<0,\cot A=-\sqrt{\csc^2A-1}$

Comment: If you read the photo, it looks like $\cos\alpha>0$ was supposed to be the extra condition.

Comment: it is a extra condition

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- From $\csc(A)$ you can find the value of $\sin(A)$, $\because \csc(A)=\frac{1}{\sin(A)} \implies \sin(A)= -\frac{2}{5}$
- Now use $\sin^{2}(A)+\cos^{2}(A)=1$ and then find $\cos(A)$.
- Now you have $\sin(A)$ and $\cos(A)$ and note that $\cot(A)=\frac{\cos(A)}{\sin(A)}$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't look pretty but here it is. 
We know that CSC = -(5/2) and that Sine has to be negative because it is less than zero. 
We also know that Cotangent is =  1/ tan = 1/ (sine/cos) = cos/sin. 
Given that CSC is = 1 / sine then it is a fair conclusion that sine is = 1/CSC. 
Since sine = 1/ CSC, then plugging in what we have for CSC we have, 1 / -(5/2) = -(2/5). Using the the common identity sine^2 + cos^2 = 1 we have that cos = sqrt(1 - sine^2). Plugging in our values once again we have, cos = sqrt(1-(-2/5)^2) = sqrt(1-(4/25)). Finally having identified that Cot = cos / sin, we plug in our values to find that Cot =  (sqrt(1-(4/25)))/(-2/5)